# How to retrieve a specific page number in an html code (for pdf file generator) and then display it elsewhere (in a TOC for example)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I am currently working on a pdf generator with html/css code. Everything is already functional, including page number generation in the footer. My current problem is that I want to create a table of contents with a dynamic page number (since depending on the content, the page numbers of the different chapters are different). Is it possible to do this with just html/css?

The generator is working properly. But I have no idea how to proceed to get the page number of the pdf file.

Comment: so, no js at all?

Comment: I would suggest extending your generator code to create objects representing the pages which you would want on the TOC. Then you can collect them and pull info out and generate the TOC using that data.  how are the page numbers being assigned by the generator?

Comment: I use Bettyblock's pdf generator. A javascript solution would be helpful too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.